# How to add multiple tags to URL in Django and Taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have this model here, where I pass the tags using TaggableManager.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

And this is how I view the data:

```
class TagView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'tagview.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_list_or_404(Post, tags__slug = self.kwargs.get('tag'))

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag'] = self.kwargs.get('tag')
        return context
```

This works as per 1 tag, but I want to include multiple tags, I've searched a lot but couldn't think of how to implement it. This is my urls.py - `path('tag/<slug:tag>/', views.TagView.as_view(), name='tagview'),`

I want something like `/tags/[django][python]/` etc..

Comment: You ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

a alternative approach witch will accomplish the same end result will be to
use query_params this means you will leave the url open to receive any arguments witch will follow the base url to this path, and you will check to see if the query_params has the 'tag' key's we are looking for.

the URL request would look something like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog?tag=python&tag=django`

#urls.py

`path('', views.TagView.as_view(), name='tagview'),`

#views.py

```
class TagView()
    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        is_there_a_tag = request.query_params.get('tag')
        if is_there_a_tag is not None:

           tag_list = request.query_params.getlist('tag')
        matches = self.posts.filter(tags__name__in=tag_list).distinct()
```

Comment: Surely `if is_there_a_tag is not None:` equates to `if is_there_a_tag:`. No?